# Wordpress ajax with async false

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Inside WordPress, I want to use ajax return value outside the function

Example

```
function get_login_member($) {
    $.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, {action: 'getloginmember'}, function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);

            if (data['id'] > 0) {
                return data;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
    });
}
```

And this function calling from

```
var row = get_login_member($);
```

The `row` variable is `undefined` because it executes before ajax request success

With Jquery ajax this can be done by made `async:false`

Is there any way to do this inside WordPress

Comment: Wordpress uses jquery. However synchronous ajax is rarely a good idea, cant you just refactor to use callback/promise

Comment: Well, I want this function to be call from multiple locations. or DRY false .

Comment: Well callbacks / promises dont effect DRY they just alter the structure of your code a bit. However, if this data is required in numerous places, why not just place it into a data attribute in the dom somewhere instead?

Comment: Yeah. Solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forget sycnhronous ajax - easiest solution is to use a callback

```
function get_login_member($, cb) {
    $.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, {action: 'getloginmember'}, function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);

            if (data['id'] > 0) {
                cb(data);
            } else {
                cb(0);
            }
    });
}
```

Then

```
get_login_member($, function(row) {
    // put your code here
});
```

Comment: Hm. i want this function to be use in multiple locations. looks like i have to change my design. and i don't see a way not to repeat the same code in multiple locations. any suggestions?

Comment: Ok. i'll just give this question a few minutes and close it. Thanks.